# Postgres: Reduce varchar size and truncate

Tags: postgresql, varchar, truncate

I currently have a Postgres 8.4 database that contains a varchar(10000) column. I'd like to change this into a varchar(255) and truncate any data that happens to be too long. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c TYPE VARCHAR(255) USING SUBSTR(c, 1, 255)`

Answer (score 5):

1) Update the column data using a substring method to truncate it

```
update t set col = substring(col from 1 for 255)
```

2) Then alter the table column

```
alter table t alter column col type varchar(255)
```

Docs here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: it seems with more recent pgsql it would be:
update t set col = substring(col from 1 for 255)
("for" replaces "to")

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE table SET column = CAST(column as varchar(255));
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE varchar(255); --not sure on this line. my memory is a bit sketchy
COMMIT;
```